# R summaries/count combinations in a data frame and display as new data frame/count matrix for column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summary

I have a large data set and need to compare all combinations between columns. The desired output would be a matrix for each column combination.

The data frame to start with could look like `Data`:

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  ID = (1:100),
  A = sample(1:10,10),
  B = sample(1:20,100,replace = T),
  C = sample(1:5,100,replace = T),
  D = sample(1:20,100,replace = T)
  )     
Data
```

and I want to know how often appears the same combination within two columns. 
(e.g. how often is a `1` in `A` in the same row with a `4` in `B`) 
for all combinations between column A to D?

I was using:

```
require(dplyr)

X1 <- ddply(Data,.(A,B),transmute, count=length(ID))
```

and get a object like:

```
     A  B count
1    1  3     1
2    1  7     1
3    1  9     2
4    1  9     2
5    1 12     1
6    1 13     1
7    1 14     1
8    1 16     1
9    1 18     1
10   1 20     1
11   2  2     1
12   2  6     1
13   2 10     1
14   2 11     1
```

But how can I get the `count` result in a matrix format?

The output for A vs. B cold look like:

```
    B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
A1  1   1   2   1   1   ...
A2  1   1   2   1   1   
A3  2   1   1   1   1   
A4  2   1   1   1   1   
A5  1   1   2   1   2   
A6  1   1   2   1   2   
A7  1   3   1   1   1   
A8  1   3   1   1   2   
A9  1   3   2   1   2   
A10 1   1   2   1   1


In the best case the result would be a `list`  containing the objects  `AB`  `AC` ...`CD` as matrix.
```

Comment: What is this `transmute`function ? Did you write it or is this from a package ? Could you add in your question which packages you load ?

Comment: `transmutate` is from the `dplyr`package

Comment: `ddply` is from `plyr` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
library(tidyverse)
X2 <-X1 %>% group_by(A,B) %>% 
  summarise(count=max(count)) %>% #use max instead of sum
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(A=paste0("A",A),B=paste0("B",B)) %>% 
  spread(B,count,fill=0)

X3 <- as.matrix(X2[,2:ncol(X2)])
rownames(X3) <- as.character(X2$A)
```

Comment: thx, looks perfect for the example, just need to get it running for my data.

Comment: I have added the last two lines to convert the result to  matrix as you wanted in your question

Comment: thanks for the matrix add, I just run in trouble using my data. As I get counts that are not possible (higher counts as IDs in the data set). Could it be that `summarise(count=sum(count))` takes the `sum` of all similar combinations but I need them only ones.

Comment: For example in `X1` is the combination `A1B9 = 2` but also displayed two times and in `X2` is `A1B9=4`. Do we need something like `unique` to get it only ones in `X2` ?

Comment: I think the problem is before in X1, for example your rows 3 and 4 are duplicated, in summarise try max instead of sum, this should work

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R using `aggregate` and `reshape`:

```
agg <- aggregate(cbind(count=ID) ~ B + A, Data, FUN=length)

rdf <- reshape(agg, timevar = "B", idvar = "A",
               drop = c("ID", "C", "D"),
               direction = "wide")

# CLEAN-UP
rdf <- with(rdf, rdf[order(A), c("A", paste0("count.", 1:20))])  # RE-ORDER ROWS AND COLS
rownames(rdf) <- NULL                                            # RESET ROW NAMES
colnames(rdf) <- gsub("count.", "B", names(rdf))                 # RENAME COL NAMES
rdf[is.na(rdf)] <- 0                                             # CONVERT NAs TO O

rdf

#     A B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 B10 B11 B12 B13 B14 B15 B16 B17 B18 B19 B20
# 1   1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   2   1
# 2   2  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  1   3   0   0   2   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
# 3   3  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   2   1   1   1   0   0   1
# 4   4  1  0  0  0  1  2  0  0  0   2   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 5   5  0  0  0  0  1  2  1  3  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
# 6   6  1  0  2  0  1  2  1  0  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
# 7   7  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   2   1   0   0   0   0   2   1   0   0   0
# 8   8  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  2  1   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
# 9   9  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   1   1   2   1   0   0   1   1   0
# 10 10  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   0   2   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0
```